# How to read php echo from server via java without getting javascript needed page?

Tags: java, php, bufferedreader, readfile, inputstreamreader

I got a java application which retrieves data from a server by reading the echo of an php script.

I am using this code:

```
String url = new UrlBuilder(URL)
            .addParameter("option", "read")
            .toString();
BufferedReader br = null;
try { br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8")); } 
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
String out = "", line;
try {
     while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
         out += line;
    }
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
try {
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return out;
```

The UrlBuilder is just encoding my url

The reply I am getting is an automatically created site which says I need javascript activated to access the site:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("261516e5343951a035c7cc4ad11521ef");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="[servers url here]";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

So how I read the actual content/source of the file?
Or how can I prevent the server from generating the file?

1.Attempt: Extract cookie value:

```
try {
    URL myUrl = new URL(URL+"?option=read");
    URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
    urlConn.connect();
    String headerName=null;
    for (int i=1; (headerName = urlConn.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
        if (headerName.equals("__test")) {           
            String cookie = urlConn.getHeaderField(i);   
            cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
            String cookieName = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("="));
            String cookieValue = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.length());
            System.out.println(cookieName);
            System.out.println(cookieValue);
        }
     }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output=none...

Where is my mistake?

Comment: an echo is just a part of the output.  you could pass it into the application as an argument?    php myfile.php | java mytest.class

Comment: The application ist doing the reading not just at the start

Comment: Java isn't just getting a site that says you need JavaScript. It's giving you the whole site, including the non-interpreted JavaScript code. The message about not having JavaScript is part of the HTML which is actually written as a warning to browsers. The only data PHP is generating fresh every time is those hex strings. The rest (including the JS) is template. Java doesn't interpret JavaScript, so you'll have to translate that JavaScript code to Java or find a way to run the JavaScript.

Comment: Your Java code is opening a URL and doing an HTTP `GET`, then reading the resulting output. How the server produces the output and the fact that the server is generating the content via a PHP echo is completely irrelevant, unless you can re-write the server-side code to produce more useful output.  The problem you need to solve here is how to run the Javascript that you receive in order to get the same result that a web browser would get.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could [add the http cookie](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html) with name '__test' to your request. JS calculated cookie value can be found with browser tools (F12). Probably 'referrer' cookie is also needed. For example: `urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "__test=<cookie from browser>; referrer=google.com/search")` before calling `urlConn.connect()`
2. Another option can be using [htmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) to run the page javascript on server side and fetch the dom after all scripts have run.

Comment: What do you mean by code?  I do not understand the question.

Comment: i tryed solution 1 but it is not working (code is in the question)

Comment: In the code above you are reading the response headers, not setting the request header. Before  urlConn.connect() you must add urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "__test=<cookie from browser>; referrer=https://www.google.com/search")